# File "windbg.exe" portable

Tags: debugging, portability

I have no administrator's rights on public terminal and can't install it is from Microsoft Tools installer
"windbg.exe" can run without the privileges, I need it to try to fix a problem
Can anybody shared this file for windows 10 64 bits release?
Thanks guys

Comment: I think this is not allowed. Install it on your own PC and copy the folder to an USB thumb drive that you can take to the other PC

Comment: I have no my own PC, Even smartphone. I am refugee. I have only public terminal. Never mind, I've got it, Enjoy, browers  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-zG4kwRFOWcc21hZ2xDbktYNXc